# Messageback like feature of Adaptive Card in Slack BlockKit

Tags: slack, slack-api, adaptive-cards, slack-block-kit

I am trying to implement messageBack feature of Adaptive Card in Slack Builder Kit where on clicking of a button I can show a default response of the bot before the response comes from the API. This could be implemented in Adaptive Card using messageBack. Is there a way to do similar thing in Slack Builder Kit template.

[image]

On clicking the button, I want to show 'Thank you for clicking' and then I want to show the response which comes from the API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the button is clicked, you can update the message that you sent with "Thank you for clicking" using the [`chat.update` method](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.update).  After that, you could update it once more to show the response from the API or just send another message via [`chat.postMessage`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage).

Alternatively, you could send an ephemeral message with the text "Thank you for clicking" using the [`chat.postEphemeral` method](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postEphemeral), which would only show up for the user that clicked the button and then send a regular message with the API contents in a later message.